# Synchronized map in spring configuration .1.2.9

Tags: spring, hashmap

We are using `Spring 1.2.9` and we are not able to use map:util

Here is the constructor of code which i have to unit test,

```
public ViewAction() {
    screen = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
    tab = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
}
```

How can i inject the hashmap and add values to the `hashmap` in the `configuration xml`.

NOTE : THE QUESTION IS NOT ABOUT USING HASHMAP. IT IS ABOUT CONFIGURING THE xml file. I tried the following and failed

```
<bean name="viewactionbean" class="com.test.helper.web.ViewAction">
    <property name="screen">
        <map>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Error while i configure the above XML file is,
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewactionbean' defined in class path resource

NOTE : Since i am using Spring 1.2.9, i am not able to use "map:util"

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem in two different ways:

1. You can use `synchronized(screen)` blocks everywhere you need to access anything in the `screen` map. That way you don't really need a `synchronizedMap` as you are already guarding your code anytime you access it.
2. You can set the `synchronizedMap` in the setter of your bean, so when Spring injects it you are placing a wrapper around it instead the actual instance provided by Spring:

Example setter method:

```
public void setScreen(Map screen) {
    this.screen = Collections.synchronizedMap(screen);
}
```

Problem with this last approach is that if you need to perform two or more operations in the map inside a single method in your bean, you still need the `synchronized(screen)` block to protect from race conditions.

To configure the map in spring you should be able to do this:

```
<bean id="..." class="....">
   <property name="screen">
     <map>
       <entry key="myKey" value="myValue" />
     </map>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like this for `HashMap`.

`private static Map<K,V> screen = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<K,V>);`

Than for `Thread` safety you can use .

```
 synchronized (screen) {

    }
```

Comment: Ankit, i need to inject the map with values from the xml file.

Comment: okay, so have you configure `bean.java` file in your `.xml` file ?

Comment: Exactly, thats what i am asking for. How can i configure it in the xml file?